# For loop how to group brackets?

Tags: php, json, for-loop, grouping, brackets

I have a question with grouping brackets together in a for loop. I use a for loop to store tournament results in array but would like to group the results by their rounds. I want to group each round. Take a look at the code below and you can compare how I would like to change the code to match the desired output:

```
$tournament_size = 16;

$upper_bracket_total_matches = $tournament_size - 1;
$lower_bracket_total_matches = $tournament_size - 2;

for($i = 1; $i <= $upper_bracket_total_matches; $i++)
{
    $upper_brackets[]= "[0,0]";
}

$upper_bracket_results = implode(",", $upper_brackets)

/* Upper Bracket Output 
[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],
[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],
[0,0],[0,0],
[0,0]
*/

/* Desired Upper Bracket Output 
[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
[[0,0],[0,0]],
[[0,0]]
*/

for($i = 1; $i <= $lower_bracket_total_matches; $i++)
{
    $lower_brackets[]= "[0,0]";
}

$lower_bracket_results = implode(",", $lower_brackets);

/* Lower Bracket Output
[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],
[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],
[0,0],[0,0],
[0,0],[0,0],
[0,0],
[0,0]
*/

/* Desired Lower bracket Output
[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
[[0,0],[0,0]],
[[0,0],[0,0]],
[[0,0]],
[[0,0]]
*/
```

Hope this is clear 
thanks for any help

Karim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: it generates stuff based on the size:

```
<?php

$tournament_size = 8;
$rounds = log($tournament_size) / log(2);

$upper_bracket_results = array();
$lower_bracket_results = array();

$curr = $tournament_size;

for ($i = 0; $i <= $rounds; $i++) {
    $inner = array();

    for ($i2 = 0; $i2 < $curr; $i2++)
        $inner[] = array(0, 0);

    $curr /= 2;
    $upper_bracket_results[] = $inner;
}

$curr = $tournament_size / 2;

for ($i = 0; $i < $rounds; $i++) {
    $inner = array();

    for ($i2 = 0; $i2 < $curr; $i2++)
        $inner[] = array(0, 0);

     $lower_bracket_results[] = $inner;
     $lower_bracket_results[] = $inner;

    $curr /= 2;
}

echo "Upper:\n\n";
echo json_encode($upper_bracket_results);
echo "\n\nLower:\n\n";
echo json_encode($lower_bracket_results);
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/cc66778db775ab):

```
Upper:

[[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],[[0,0],[0,0]],[[0,0]]]

Lower:

[[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],[[0,0],[0,0]],[[0,0],[0,0]],[[0,0]],[[0,0]]]
```

Comment: thanks but when i try this code i get a parse syntax error for $inner[] = [0, 0]; ?

Comment: I've changed it to `array()` instead of `[]`. PHP 5.4 supports `[]` notation.

Comment: thanks i got the code to run now upper bracket is fine but lower bracket is outputting too much brackets there should be 14 [0,0] can you please check this. thanks agian

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that difference. Please try the updated code, I edited my post.

Comment: Sweet, if this answered your question, please consider accepting it by ticking the checkmark.